# Django rest - Custom authentication backend with browsable api

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I am using `Django 1.11` and `Django rest framework 3.6.2`
I created a custom authentication backend:

```
MyAuthBackend(rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication): 
    # ...
```

and added it to the `settings.py` file:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {  
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES' : ('path.to.MyAuthBackend',)

}
```

I also tried to extend `SessionAuthentication` without success

My issue is that users are trying to log in via the `browsable api` and it looks like the authentication backend that the browsable api is using is not the default one.

Where can I change that? I have to use my own auth backend in the browsable api,
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to use `BasicAuthentication` in the browseable api (without changing a whole bunch of its internals).

Consider keeping the SessionAuthentication alongside your new one, you can use basic authentication in your app and session authentication in the browsable api:

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'path.to.MyAuthBackend',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
),
```

Comment: I am using a third service for authentication with different database I can`t use the default

Comment: Sounds like you've got to extend SessionAuthentication then, where did it go wrong for you?

Comment: Looks like it first looks if user is existing in the database and then calling authenticate function. But, my users database is empty all users are existing in different service

Comment: You probably need to override `.authenticate` method (and don't call super() in it)

Comment: I think I found a solution. You need to customize Django's (!) authentication `rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication` just relies on it. I need a bit more time to play with it, maybe this weekend.

Comment: @OzBar-Shalom in the meantime, check out this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/